# How to make a top-bottom vertical line

Tags: html, css

How do I make a vertical line from the top to bottom of my site. That should cover the whole height of my site

I have tried height: 100%;, but they disappear.

```
 .vertical-hr {
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 0.1%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
 }

 <div class="vertical-hr"></div>
```

Comment: no need to delete and repeat the same question, it will get closed the same way. If the duplicate doesn't solve your issue, edit to say way

Comment: @TemaniAfif it isn't even close my friend. Please remove the duplicate

Comment: read the duplicate and you understand your issue and why the code isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Put vh instead of %

```
height: 100vh;
```

and remove `float`

try the code snippet

```css
.vertical-hr {
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="vertical-hr"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't see the line when I implement this to my site.

Comment: It's working fine, Try this edited one. Otherwise share code of your parent divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using a fixed position.
Give it a higher stack order(z-index) so that it always appear in the front.

```
<style>
    .vertical-hr {
        width: 20px;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9999999999;
    }
</style>
<div class="vertical-hr"></div>
```